# Query optimisation. Getting row with max column value

Tags: sql, linq

is it possible to have a better optimisation of this linq query:

```
var query = Context.books.Where(book=> book.Author == "Murakami"
                                        && book.Year = 2004
                                        && book.price ==
                                        Context.books.Where(book => book.Author == Murakami")
                                        .Max(c => c.price));
```

I'm interested in the Max part because Author is the same as a little bit above

Comment: well, you can always DESC sort by price and only select the first?

Comment: What you do with your query : return all books (might be more than one, or zero) from Murakami 2004, if their price is equivalent to the max price of all Murakami's books. I suppose you rather want THE (1) most expensive book of Murakami in 2004, which is slightly different... (but I may be wrong)

Comment: No, I want 0..n books. I might have confused you, but the main goal is to have the most productive sql.

Comment: @Najzero, no,  desc operation has more O value and requires more operations than Max value, that's why it wount be more productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the most Expensive book from Murakami in 2004

*This will retrieve 0 or 1 book.*

```
var mostExpensiveBook = Context.books.Where(book => book.Author = "Murakami" &&
                                        book.Year == 2004)
                         .OrderByDescending(m => m.price)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

if you want all the books from Murakami 2004 which have a price equivalent to the most expensive Murakami's book, you may rewrite your query to (equivalent to your query, just avoiding repeating "Murakami" and using a let keyword).

*this will retrieve 0-n book(s).*

```
var books = context.Books.Where(m => m.Author == "Murakami");

var mostExpensiveBooks = from book in books 
                         let mostExpensivePrice = books.Max(x => x.price)
                         where book.price == mostExpensivePrice &&
                               book.Year == 2004
                         select book;
```